# SearchView automatically closed

Tags: android, searchview

In my case, I have `activity` with 2 containers for `fragments`.
One container show `Fragment` with list, second show detail information on the selected list item. Second container `GONE` by default.

In activity I have `SearchView`, which instance I get from fragment like that:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        rxSearchView = (RxSearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        rxSearchView.setSearchListener(taskListPresenter);
        rxSearchView.setOnCloseListener(() -> {
            taskListPresenter.clearSearch();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

and, I use method `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `OnCreateView();`

**Problem case:**

**1.User click on the searchView, and get filtered element:**

[image]

**2. User click on the element, calling next method:**

```
`((MainActivity)getActivity()).showSecondaryFragment(TaskDetailFragment.newInstance();`
```

In `MainActivity` it's look like that:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.ltRightContainer, baseFragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit();
```

After that, searchView automatically closed, like screen below.

[image]

How fix that moment? I don't want it automatically closing.

`RxSearchView` just wrapper with `RxJava` implementation, without ovverride methods.

Comment: I think `SearchView` will close automatically as soon as it loses focus. You may subclass and change that logics.

Comment: @azizbekian Hi, was tried ovverride methods with focus, it's not helped.
Trying to find right method

Answer (score 0):

Second fragment just  call method `setupMenu(R.menu.menu_my_task);`
It makes `searchView` from first `fragment` close.